# What is the highest melting temperature of chocolate?

Tags: chocolate

A pure chocolate bar will always melt at 33 Celsius, as several of my books assure me.

But an answer to another question [claims that there are chocolates with a higher melting point](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/43967/4638).

What kind of chocolate can do this? What does it contain? How much actual chocolate would be inside it, and what is the rest made of? What is the highest melting temperature which can be achieved by such a product? What would be some generic terms for it - if I wanted some and went to a chocolate shop, what would I have to ask for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical tricks used by chocolate manufacturers is to change the viscosity of chocolate by adding a gel like xanthan gum or glycerine. The other trick is to incorporate more water into the chocolate with the aid of an emulsifier such as lecithin. All these techniques are hard to do at home as they require many hours of stirring the chocolate to avoid grittiness. [Patents](http://www.google.com/patents?id=floKAAAAEBAJ&zoom=4&pg=PA4#v=onepage&q&f=false) often give recipes.

One can buy chocolate with higher melting points. [Callebaut Volcano](http://www.barry-callebaut.com/84?release=5256) melts at 55°C, the highest melting point for a commercial chocolate that I know of, but is not yet on sale. Many of the commercial chocolate bars, such as the wartime [Hershey's Tropical Bar](http://www.hersheyarchives.org/essay/details.aspx?EssayId=39) use chocolate that incorporate these techniques as do the [Nestle Toll House morsels](http://www.verybestbaking.com/products/toll-house/morsels.aspx).